# Edge-adding conjecture for graphs

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics

For any set $X$ we let $[X]^2 = \big\{\{x, y\}: x\neq y \in X\big\}$. Consider the following statement:

> (S) : If $G =(V,E)$ is a simple, undirected graph such that $E \neq [X]^2$, then there is $e^* \in [X]^2 \setminus E$ such that $G \not \cong (V, E\cup\{e^*\})$.

For finite graphs, (S) is true since adding any edge changes the degree sequence. Does (S) hold for infinite graphs as well?

Comment: What about taking the disjoint union of all possible finite graphs, each one repeated countably many times?

Comment: Brilliant - this does work! Would you like to post it as an answer, so I can accept & upvote it? Or would you prefer that I delete the question. Maybe it is interesting for connected graphs

Comment: My answer to your similar question about deleting edges works as well: Take infinitely many disjoint edges together with infinitely many isolated vertices.  Although unlike the Rado graph or Thomas Bloom's answer, this doesn't work for every non-edge.

Comment: I think the down-voters are being rather harsh: while the random graph gives a simple answer, it's hardly the most intuitive object one meets in mathematics.

Comment: Thanks @MarkWildon - I agree that the random graph is not a solution that jumps to the "pedestrian mathematician's" mind immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - for a countexample, take the disjoint union of all possible finite graphs, each repeated countably many times.

There is a similar counterexample even if we ask that the graph be connected - just add all possible edges between vertices from different 'copies'.

Answer (score 3):

For a connected counterexample you could take the Rado graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph). It shouldn't be too hard to prove that when you add an edge, the resulting graph will still satisfy the extension property, which characterizes the Rado graph.